# Banshee started crashing a couple of seconds after launch

Tags: banshee

Banshee started crashing a couple of seconds after launch, It used to run without problems but now it crashes after launch. I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Here is the terminal output:

```
[Info  09:51:25.081] Running Banshee 2.6.2: [Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (linux-gnu, x86_64) @ 2014-08-12 14:04:38 UTC]

(Banshee:27991): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: attempting to add an interface (AtkComponent) to class (__gtksharp_48_Hyena_Gui_BaseWidgetAccessible) after class_init

(Banshee:27991): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: attempting to add an interface (AtkTable) to class (__gtksharp_49_Hyena_Data_Gui_Accessibility_ListViewAccessible+601+5b+5bBanshee_Collection_TrackInfo+2c+20Banshee_Core+2c+20Version+3d2_6_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3dnull+5d+5d) after class_init

(Banshee:27991): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: attempting to add an interface (AtkSelection) to class (__gtksharp_49_Hyena_Data_Gui_Accessibility_ListViewAccessible+601+5b+5bBanshee_Collection_TrackInfo+2c+20Banshee_Core+2c+20Version+3d2_6_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3dnull+5d+5d) after class_init

(Banshee:27991): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: attempting to add an interface (AtkTable) to class (__gtksharp_55_Hyena_Data_Gui_Accessibility_ListViewAccessible+601+5b+5bBanshee_Collection_Database_QueryFilterInfo+601+5b+5bSystem_String+2c+20mscorlib+2c+20Version+3d4_0_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3db77a5c561934e089+5d+5d+2c+20Banshee_Services+2c+20Version+3d2_6_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3dnull+5d+5d) after class_init

(Banshee:27991): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: attempting to add an interface (AtkSelection) to class (__gtksharp_55_Hyena_Data_Gui_Accessibility_ListViewAccessible+601+5b+5bBanshee_Collection_Database_QueryFilterInfo+601+5b+5bSystem_String+2c+20mscorlib+2c+20Version+3d4_0_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3db77a5c561934e089+5d+5d+2c+20Banshee_Services+2c+20Version+3d2_6_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3dnull+5d+5d) after class_init

(Banshee:27991): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: attempting to add an interface (AtkTable) to class (__gtksharp_61_Hyena_Data_Gui_Accessibility_ListViewAccessible+601+5b+5bBanshee_Collection_ArtistInfo+2c+20Banshee_Core+2c+20Version+3d2_6_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3dnull+5d+5d) after class_init

(Banshee:27991): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: attempting to add an interface (AtkSelection) to class (__gtksharp_61_Hyena_Data_Gui_Accessibility_ListViewAccessible+601+5b+5bBanshee_Collection_ArtistInfo+2c+20Banshee_Core+2c+20Version+3d2_6_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3dnull+5d+5d) after class_init

(Banshee:27991): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: attempting to add an interface (AtkTable) to class (__gtksharp_67_Hyena_Data_Gui_Accessibility_ListViewAccessible+601+5b+5bBanshee_Collection_YearInfo+2c+20Banshee_Core+2c+20Version+3d2_6_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3dnull+5d+5d) after class_init

(Banshee:27991): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: attempting to add an interface (AtkSelection) to class (__gtksharp_67_Hyena_Data_Gui_Accessibility_ListViewAccessible+601+5b+5bBanshee_Collection_YearInfo+2c+20Banshee_Core+2c+20Version+3d2_6_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3dnull+5d+5d) after class_init

(Banshee:27991): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: attempting to add an interface (AtkTable) to class (__gtksharp_73_Hyena_Data_Gui_Accessibility_ListViewAccessible+601+5b+5bBanshee_Collection_AlbumInfo+2c+20Banshee_Core+2c+20Version+3d2_6_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3dnull+5d+5d) after class_init

(Banshee:27991): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: attempting to add an interface (AtkSelection) to class (__gtksharp_73_Hyena_Data_Gui_Accessibility_ListViewAccessible+601+5b+5bBanshee_Collection_AlbumInfo+2c+20Banshee_Core+2c+20Version+3d2_6_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3dnull+5d+5d) after class_init
[Info  09:51:25.955] Updating web proxy from GConf
[Info  09:51:26.037] All services are started 0.793908

(Banshee:27991): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 112 was not found when attempting to remove it

(Banshee:27991): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 144 was not found when attempting to remove it

(Banshee:27991): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 213 was not found when attempting to remove it
[Warn  09:51:26.797] Forcefully breaking out of RCS loop b/c change in total_width less than 1.0
[Info  09:51:26.826] nereid Client Started
[Info  09:51:26.875] GStreamer version 1.2.4.0, gapless: True, replaygain: False
[Info  09:51:26.893] AppleDeviceSource is ignoring unmounted volume Recovery
[Info  09:51:26.969] AppleDeviceSource is ignoring unmounted volume OS

(Banshee:27991): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 589 was not found when attempting to remove it

(Banshee:27991): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 587 was not found when attempting to remove it

(Banshee:27991): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 595 was not found when attempting to remove it

(Banshee:27991): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 708 was not found when attempting to remove it

(Banshee:27991): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 594 was not found when attempting to remove it
*** Error in `banshee': double free or corruption (!prev): 0x00007f0cb801d020 ***
Stacktrace:

  at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Gtk.Application.gtk_main () <0xffffffff>
  at Gtk.Application.Run () <0x0000b>
  at Banshee.Gui.GtkBaseClient.Run () <0x000cb>
  at Banshee.Gui.GtkBaseClient.Startup () <0x00042>
  at Hyena.Gui.CleanRoomStartup.Startup (Hyena.Gui.CleanRoomStartup/StartupInvocationHandler) <0x0009e>
  at Banshee.Gui.GtkBaseClient.Startup<T> () <0x000c3>
  at Banshee.Gui.GtkBaseClient.Startup<T> (string[]) <0x000f7>
  at Nereid.Client.Main (string[]) <0x00017>
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>
  at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly (System.AppDomain,System.Reflection.Assembly,string[]) <0xffffffff>
  at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssemblyInternal (System.Reflection.Assembly,string[]) <0x00047>
  at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly (string,System.Security.Policy.Evidence,string[]) <0x0003b>
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly (string,System.Security.Policy.Evidence,string[]) <0xffffffff>
  at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly (string) <0x00027>
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly (string) <0xffffffff>
  at Booter.Booter.BootClient (string) <0x0006b>
  at Booter.Booter.Main () <0x001db>
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) object.runtime_invoke_void (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>
```

Native stacktrace:

```
banshee() [0x4b73d8]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x10340) [0x7f0d311f4340]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x39) [0x7f0d30e54cc9]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x148) [0x7f0d30e580d8]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x73f24) [0x7f0d30e91f24]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x801fe) [0x7f0d30e9e1fe]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavutil.so.52(av_freep+0xc) [0x7f0cd44a7fcc]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec.so.54(avcodec_close+0xf1) [0x7f0cd4720124]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstlibav.so(+0xb030) [0x7f0cd574a030]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstlibav.so(+0x18d93) [0x7f0cd5757d93]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstlibav.so(+0x18f3f) [0x7f0cd5757f3f]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstaudio-1.0.so.0(+0x1a351) [0x7f0d13700351]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.0.so.0(gst_element_change_state+0x22) [0x7f0d12929232]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.0.so.0(+0x4d90c) [0x7f0d1292990c]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.0.so.0(+0x33659) [0x7f0d1290f659]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstplayback.so(+0xd913) [0x7f0d05f83913]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.0.so.0(gst_element_change_state+0x22) [0x7f0d12929232]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.0.so.0(+0x4d90c) [0x7f0d1292990c]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.0.so.0(+0x33659) [0x7f0d1290f659]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.0.so.0(+0x6af7b) [0x7f0d12946f7b]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.0.so.0(gst_element_change_state+0x22) [0x7f0d12929232]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.0.so.0(gst_element_change_state+0x21a) [0x7f0d1292942a]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.0.so.0(+0x4d90c) [0x7f0d1292990c]
/usr/lib/banshee/libbanshee.so(+0x652c) [0x7f0d1393652c]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.0.so.0(+0x3af71) [0x7f0d12916f71]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_main_context_dispatch+0x135) [0x7f0d2db40ce5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(+0x49048) [0x7f0d2db41048]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_main_loop_run+0x6a) [0x7f0d2db4130a]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0(gtk_main+0xa7) [0x7f0d23937447]
[0x401edac5]
```

Debug info from gdb:

```
Could not attach to process.  If your uid matches the uid of the target
process, check the setting of /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope, or try
again as the root user.  For more details, see /etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf
ptrace: Operation not permitted.
No threads.

=================================================================
Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================

Aborted (core dumped)
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Michael, I'd the same issue and got it fixed by deleting Banshee's config files.

Open your Terminal and under `~/.config` find and remove the `banshee-1` folder.

```
$ rm -rf banshee-1
```

Hope that helps!

([source](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=191299#p991420))